# Is it possible to modify a grep pattern while reading a continuous stream without killing the process?

Tags: bash, grep, stream, zsh

To grep a continuous stream, we can pass `--line_buffered`:

```
tail -f file | grep --line-buffered my_pattern
```

Is there a bash program or other way to modify `my_pattern` live without killing the parent process?

Comment: No. You can use `awk`, `python`, `perl` or something instead to add a mechanism to swap out the pattern

Comment: --line-buffered "Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered otherwise" .    how does this relevant?